# Filter based on COUNT behaving strange

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that shows rows that have multiple duplicates of ActivityDate,TaskId, and EnteredBy:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [DailyTaskHours] t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ActivityDate
        ,taskId
        ,EnteredBy
    FROM [DailyTaskHours]
    GROUP BY EnteredBy
        ,taskId
        ,ActivityDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t2 ON (
        t1.ActivityDate = t2.ActivityDate
        AND t1.taskId = t2.taskId
        AND t1.EnteredBy = t2.EnteredBy
        AND t1.Hours != 0
        )
ORDER BY TaskId
```

It looks to be almost working but there is an anomaly:

[image]

The above highlighted row is returned even though there is only 1 taskId in view (2732). I only want it to return if there are > 1 duplicate TaskId's.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit Requested Select:

```
SELECT ActivityDate ,taskId ,EnteredBy FROM [DailyTaskHours] where TaskId = 2732
```

[image]

^ This explains why it is showing up, but why arent both of the 10/22 entries showing up?

Comment: Duplicate task IDs for what?

Comment: Can you do the following select: SELECT ActivityDate
        ,taskId
        ,EnteredBy
    FROM [DailyTaskHours] where TaskId = 2732

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested select. @Andrew, duplicate taskId data in the TaskId column.

Comment: Guessing that the hours for the two 10/22 entries = 0.

Comment: ^ You are correct, one of the two hours is 0, how can I prevent either from being returned if this is the case?

Comment: Add a where clause to your subquery (t2) to filter them out.

Comment: You have the answer, would you like to post it as one? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join filters on `t1.hours != 0`, but your subquery (`t2`) does not have that same filter.  Add it like so:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [DailyTaskHours] t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ActivityDate
       ,taskId
       ,EnteredBy
    FROM [DailyTaskHours]
    WHERE hours != 0
    GROUP BY EnteredBy
       ,taskId
       ,ActivityDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t2 ON (
       t1.ActivityDate = t2.ActivityDate
       AND t1.taskId = t2.taskId
       AND t1.EnteredBy = t2.EnteredBy
       AND t1.Hours != 0
       )
ORDER BY TaskId
```